# Sort array by keys ascending and nominate a "sticky" key to be first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, sticky

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$array = array (
  "B" => array ("Banana", "Yello"),
  "O" => array ("Orange", "Orange"),
  "A" => array ("Apple", "Green"),
  "S" => array ("Strawberry", "Red")
);

$o = $array['O']; // this is the letter O not zero
asort($array);
array_unshift($array, $o);
```

Now I want to reorder the array using `asort()` but keep "O" as the first entry:

```
O, A, B, S
```

The problem here is that I get

```
O, A, B, O, S
```

How to get rid of the second "O"?

NB: I already asked a similar question but with a different array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040873/asort-php-array-and-keep-one-entry-at-the-top)

Answer (score 2):

You just need `unset($array['O']);`

```
<?php
    $array = array (
  "B" => array ("Banana", "Yello"),
  "O" => array ("Orange", "Orange"),
  "A" => array ("Apple", "Green"),
  "S" => array ("Strawberry", "Red")
);

$o = $array['O']; // this is the letter O not zero
asort($array);
unset($array['O']);
array_unshift($array, $o);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/855161

Answer (score 2):

Try this to retain array key:

```
$array = array (
  "B" => array ("Banana", "Yello"),
  "O" => array ("Orange", "Orange"),
  "A" => array ("Apple", "Green"),
  "S" => array ("Strawberry", "Red")
);

$key = 'O';

asort($array);
$array = (array_key_exists($key, $array)) ? array($key => $array[$key]) + $array : $array;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

http://www.phpwin.org/s/ltHbIV

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

EDITED with credit to @salathe

Comment: This could just be: `asort($array); $array = array("O" => $array["O"]) + $array;`

Comment: @salathe, thanks for this nice and clean suggestion. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Better than calling multiple functions would be to use the one function that was designed to do custom key sorting.

*Note this custom sort will not fail when the sticky key is missing, so there is no need to check beforehand if the key exists in the array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/42nIm))

```
$sticky = 'O';

uksort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => [$a !== $sticky, $a] <=> [$b !== $sticky, $b]
);

var_export($array);
```

The `!==` comparison is used because `false` is naturally sorted before `true`.  Think of `false` being `0` and `true` being `1`.

The algorithm sorts first by "sticky-ness", then alphabetically.